# Service bus topic. Is it synchronous or asynchronous write to subscriptions

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Is the write to subscriptions asynchronous and success is returned before messages are written in all subscriptions.

What happens if a subscription(and all replica) is down at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus client communicates over AMQP. A message has to be received by broker and acknowledged to the client for the client to consider sending/publishing operation to be successful. If broker is unreachable for any reason, client will throw an exception.

I.e. Azure Service Bus is **not** Store and Forward like MSMQ.